# Loop through specific indexes in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a table with products and it's variants.

Each one has an index on the table, for instance:

```
[0] Product 1

[1] Variant 1

[2] Variant 2

[3] Product 2
```

etc..

I've assigned to an associative array all the variant's indexes along with their value, for instance:

```
[1] Variant 1 : 13

[2] Variant 2 : 15

[18] Variant 3: 32
```

Now I want to loop through the table using only the indexes I got on my array.

Is there a way to loop through an element using specific indexes? ( So I don't have to loop through the whole thing and execute what I want whenever it matches ). Something similar to this pseudocode:

`loop through my_table on index = [1,2,18]`

**Edit** for Joseph Marikle:

The code part for the array is this:

```
var variants_index = [];
  $.each($('.variant'),function(){
    variants_index[$(this).index()] = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
  });
```

typing `typeof(variants_index)` we get: `object` and typing the var in the console, we get `Array` and, typing `Array.isArray(variants_index)` we get `true`

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you use a 2D array?

Comment: I'm trying to write my problem as a more simple example.. What I'm actually doing is a little more complex.

Comment: If you're already generating an array containing the indexes you need to find, why not just use that loop to do the work you need?

Comment: After trying this approach I might be doing that.. It's a mix of a real question and curiosity.

Comment: Just to be clear, javascript doesn't really support associative arrays.  Is this an object or is it something along the lines of `[undefined × 1, "Variant 1 : 13", "Variant 2 : 15", undefined × 15, "Variant 3: 32"]`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I'll update the question for you

Comment: @Onilol Thanks.  Using `typeof` against an array will always return "object" in javascript.  To test if a variable holds an array, you should use [`Array.isArray(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).  Your scenario is as I described in my first comment.  Both answers below are how I would accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through your array of indices that you are interested in and use their values as an index to your array containing product info.

```
var indexToCheck = [1,2,18];

for(var i = 0; i < indexToCheck.length; i++){
  var productInfo = myProducts[indexToCheck[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through my_table on index = [1,2,8] (changed the 18 to 8 for simplicity)

Since that's the core of the problem, let's try to solve it.

```
index = [1,2,8]
my_table = [5,4,6,7,3,8,2,9,0,1]
for (i=0;i<index.length;i++){
    console.log(my_table[index[i]]);
}
```

This would get the numbers from "index" as use them as indexes to access positions in my_table